# Echo with obfuscation

Tags: bash, security

I need to print some variables to the screen but I need to preferebly obfuscate the first few characters and I was wondering if there was an echo command in bash that can obfuscate the first characters of a secret value while printing it to the terminal:

```
echo 'secretvalue'
********lue
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other answers mask a fixed amount of characters from the start, with the plaintext suffix varying in length. An alternative would be to leave a fixed amount of characters in plaintext, and to vary the length of the masked part. I don't know which one is more useful, but here's the other choice:

```
#!/bin/bash
mask() {
        local n=3                    # number of chars to leave
        local a="${1:0:${#1}-n}"     # take all but the last n chars
        local b="${1:${#1}-n}"       # take the final n chars 
        printf "%s%s\n" "${a//?/*}" "$b"   # substitute a with asterisks
}

mask abcde
mask abcdefghijkl
```

This prints `**cde` and `*********jkl`.

---

If you like, you could also modify `n` for short strings to make sure a majority of the string gets masked. E.g. this would make sure at least three characters are masked even for short strings. (so `abcde` -> `***de`, and `abc` -> `***`):

```
mask() {
        local n=3
        [[ ${#1} -le 5 ]] && n=$(( ${#1} - 3 ))
        local a="${1:0:${#1}-n}"
        local b="${1:${#1}-n}"
        printf "%s%s\n" "${a//?/*}" "$b"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

One option would be to force yourself to use a function instead of `echo`, such as:

```
obfuprint() {
  if [ "${#1}" -ge 8 ]
  then
    printf '%s\n' "${1/????????/********}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "${1//?/*}"
  fi
}
```

Then you could call `obfuprint 'secretvalue'` and receive `********lue` (with a trailing newline).  The function uses parameter expansion to search for the first eight characters of the passed-in value and replaces them with eight asterisks. If the incoming value is shorter than eight characters, they are all replaced with asterisks. Thanks to [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) for pointing out my initial assumption of eight-or-more character inputs!

---

Inspired by [ilkkachu's flexible masking answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507474/117549), I thought it'd be interesting to add a variation that randomly masks some percentage of the string:

```
obfuprintperc () {
  local perc=75  ## percent to obfuscate
  local i=0
  for((i=0; i < ${#1}; i++))
  do
    if [ $(( $RANDOM % 100 )) -lt "$perc" ]
    then
        printf '%s' '*'
    else
        printf '%s' "${1:i:1}"
    fi
  done
  echo
}
```

This relies on bash's `$RANDOM` special variable; it simply loops through each character of the input and decides whether to mask that character or print it. Sample output:

```
$ obfuprintperc 0123456789
0*****6*8*
$ obfuprintperc 0123456789
012***678*
$ obfuprintperc 0123456789
**********
$ obfuprintperc 0123456789
*****56***
$ obfuprintperc 0123456789
0*******8*
```

Comment: To be frank, I do not like random masking.  A determined shoulder surfer will eventually get my secrets by pretending to like making small talk with me.

Comment: Certainly, displaying sensitive information should be done carefully!  I presented random masking as an alternative to fixed-prefix masking and variable-prefix masking.

Comment: I am not a fan of fixed-prefix or variable-prefix masking either, but with those there exists a "kernel" of my secret that remains secret.  With random masking, there is no "kernel".  Eventually everything will be revealed to those patient enough.

Answer (score 9):

A `zsh` variant that masks three quarters of the text:

```
mask() printf '%s\n' ${(l[$#1][*])1:$#1*3/4}
```

Example:

```
$ mask secretvalue
********lue
$ mask 12345678
******78
$ mask 1234
***4
```

To mask the first 8 chars:

```
mask() printf '%s\n' ${(l[$#1][*])1:8}
```

To mask all but the last 3 chars:

```
mask() printf '%s\n' ${(l[$#1][*])1: -3}
```

To mask a random number of characters:

```
mask() printf '%s\n' ${(l[$#1][*])1: RANDOM%$#1}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try piping to `sed`. For example, to replace the first 8 characters of a string with asterisks, you could pipe to the `sed 's/^......../********/'` command, e.g.:

```bsh
$ echo 'secretvalue' | sed 's/^......../********/'
********lue
```

You can also define a function that does this:

```bsh
obsecho () { echo "$1" | sed 's/^......../*********/'; }
```

Comment: I'd suggest [`printf` over `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) so that you're not subject to interpreting data such as `\r` or `\n`

Comment: @JeffSchaller This is one of the reasons why I post on SE. Good point. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It's one of the many things *I've* learned in my time here, as well! Happy to pass it along!

Comment: No need to use a pipe when you can use a herestring instead: `sed 's/^......../********/' <<< 'secretvalue'`

Comment: @roaima It's actually a temporary regular file. You can see it if you do `bash -c 'lsof -d0 -a -p $$ 2>/dev/null' <<< foo`.

Comment: @JoL yes ok. Wrong terminology on my part, sorry. { Process writes to file. Then process reads from file } or { Process writes to pipe and process reads from pipe }.

Answer (score 2):

Another option in Bash, if you don’t mind one simple `eval` you can do it with a couple of `printf`:

```bsh
# example data
password=secretvalue
chars_to_show=3

# the real thing
eval "printf '*%.0s' {1..$((${#password} - chars_to_show))}"
printf '%s\n' "${password: -chars_to_show}"
```

But be careful:

- fix the above as you need when `${#password}` is less than `${chars_to_show}`
- `eval` can be very dangerous with untrusted input: here it can be considered safe because its input comes only from safe sources, ie the length of `${password}` and the value of `${chars_to_show}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "helloworld" | sed -E "s/(.{3})(.{5})/\1*****/"
hel*****ld
```

`(.{3})` - the masking starts after the 3rd letter
`(.{5})` - the quantity of letters that will be replaced by `*****`. `(.{255})` will be the maximum allowed on the MacOS BSD `sed`.

`sed -E` can be changed with `sed -r`, but `sed -E` is more portable across shells.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some *toy* Bash scripts to play with that show how to combine regex-like search with string substitution.

### `strip_str.sh`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_str="${1}"
_filter="${2:-'apl'}"
echo "${_str//[${_filter}]/}"
```

```bsh
strip_str.sh 'apple-foo bar'
# -> e-foo br
strip_str.sh 'apple-foo bar' 'a'
# -> pple-foo br
```

### `privatize_str.sh`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_str="${1}"
_filter="${2:-'apl'}"
_replace="${3:-'*'}"
echo "${_str//[${_filter}]/${_replace}}"
```

```bsh
privatize_str.sh 'apple-foo bar'
# -> ****e-foo b*r
```

### `restricted_str.sh`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_str="${1}"
_valid="${2:-'a-z'}"
_replace="${3:-''}"
echo "${_str//[^${_valid}]/${_replace}}"
```

```bsh
restricted_str.sh 'apple-foo bar'
# -> applefoobar
```

---

Key takeaways

- `[a-z 0-9]` is totally valid, and handy, as a `<search>` within `${_var_name//<search>/<replace>}` for Bash
- `^`, within this context, is the reverse or `not` for regex-like searches
- Built-ins are generally faster and often are more concise, especially when it cuts out unneeded piping

> While I get that `printf` is *better* in nearly all use cases the above code uses `echo` so as to not overly confuse what's going on.

### `obfuscate_str.sh`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_str="${1}"
_start="${2:-6}"
_header="$(for i in {1..${_start}}; do echo -n '*'; done)"
echo "${_header}${_str:${_start}}"
```

```bsh
obfuscate_str.sh 'apple-foo bar' 3
# -> ***le-foo bar
```